# Шифрование с открытым ключом

Tags: python, шифрование

Мне надо осуществить обмен данными между двумя информационными-системами. Данные хочу передавать в зашифрованном виде. Слышал о том, что возможно шифрование по ключу, те на обеих сторонах известен ключ, по нему я шифрую данные. Какой алгоритм использовать? Не хочу ничего придумывать, хочу воспользоваться API. Подскажите, куда смотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю в вашем случае вполне подойдёт [RSA](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa).
Вот конкретный простой [пример](http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#encryption-and-decryption).

Answer (score 1):

Смотреть в сторону rsa или aes шифрования. [Вот](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa), к примеру, либа для RSA.

Comment: хеширование и шифрование разные вещи...

Comment: верно. поправлю ответ

Comment: вот еще статья хорошая http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/infosecurity/39653/

Answer (score 1):

Открытый ключ - это ассиметричное шифрование. Посмотрите по ссылкам:

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pypgp/

Answer (score 0):

можно исспользовать blowfish в виде модуля для питона где то есть в сети

Answer (score 0):

Вот гнездо [python-gnupg](http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/), хотя можно и [отсюда](http://packages.python.org/python-gnupg/) взять. Ну и пару слов про шифрование с открытым ключом. Оно обычно требует немало вычислений, и для скорости используются смешанные схемы, где алгоритмом с открытым ключом шифруется ключ сессии, а сам поток данных  шифруется уже алгоритмом с секретным ключом (симметричным), с использованием данного ключа. А шифрование сообщений алгоритмами с открытым ключом -- экзотика.